# else if & curly brackets

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, parentheses

Why do these two code snippets have different outputs ?

The only difference between them is the curly brackets around each if/else-if statement, but that shouldn't matter here, right?

```
while (1){
    if (i>=n&&j<0)
        break;

    else if (j<0)
        if (Arr[i])
            c++;

    else if (i>=n)
        if(Arr[j])
            c++;

    else if (Arr[i]==1&&Arr[j]==1)
        c+=2;

    i++;
    j--;
}
```

..

```
while (1){
    if (i>=n&&j<0){
        break;
    }
    else if (j<0){
        if (Arr[i])
            c++;
    }
    else if (i>=n){
        if(Arr[j])
            c++;
    }
    else if (Arr[i]==1&&Arr[j]==1){
        c+=2;
    }
    i++;
    j--;
}
```

Comment: What happens if a nested if fails, in the first case? What gets called subsequently?

Comment: `{ }` are braces.  `( )` are parentheses.

Comment: Braces ensures the structure of the if...else if ladder is correct and does not decay into nested IF's

Comment: All [coding standards](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~eno/coding/CCodingStandard.html#brace) should require / suggest using braces

Comment: If you used some editor supporting auto-indentation then you would see the differences :)

Comment: Indentation is solely for making the structure of code visible to humans; it makes no difference to the compiler.  This means the indentation can show the human an illusion that does not match the reality seen by the compiler --- effectively, the indentation can lie.

Comment: Stepping through questionable code in a debugger can be quite enlightening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you format correctly the first code snippet

```
while (1){
    if (i>=n&&j<0)
        break;

    else if (j<0)
        if (Arr[i])
            c++;

        else if (i>=n)
            if(Arr[j])
                c++;
            else if (Arr[i]==1&&Arr[j]==1)
                c+=2;

    i++;
    j--;
}
```

then it is seen that else or else if correspond to the closest if statement.